# Update a column to the same value based on constraints from other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this on SQL Server:

```
code description percentage
123  abc         1
123  oke         0
123  cfd         0
234  kde         2
234  kfc         0
234  kfc         0
```

How can I update the description of all '0 percentage' records to non-zero percentage record for each code group? e.g. the result I'm after is:

```
code description percentage
123  abc         1
123  abc         0
123  abc         0
234  kde         2
234  kde         0
234  kde         0
```

Comment: For what database?  And post a query to demonstrate that you've tried.

Comment: for SQL server - my query simply doesn't work and I don't know what query could achieve that...

Comment: what you're asking doesn't match with the info showed- If you want to update records to '1 percentage' why are you updateing a field with '2 percentage' ?

Comment: to Elvieejo: yes you're right - it's an oversight I made...already corrected.

Comment: if I have a percentage 1 and 2 in same code, which one should I choose to update a zero percentage ?

Comment: To Elvieejo: good question and thank you for pointing it out - but it has only 1 non-zero percentage for a code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE Table  
SET description=(SELECT TOP 1 description 
                 FROM Table t
                 WHERE t.code = Table.code AND percentage<>'0') 
WHERE percentage='0'
```

Comment: Only SQL Server supports `TOP`

Comment: it doesn't work mate - here's my try with the error messages:

update tmp_awo_pat a
set a.awo_short_description = 
(select top 1 awo_short_description from tmp_awo_pat where tmp_awo_pat.awo_pat_code = a.awo_pat_code and assign_percentage <> 0)
where a.assign_percentage = 0

Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'a'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Answer (score 2):

```
Update T1 set description = T2.Description from YourTable T1 
inner join 
(    select code, description from yourTable group by code, description
    where percentage <> 0 ) T2 on T1.Code = T2.Code
where T1.Code = 0
```

**Edited**
This consider that each group has only zero on only one another description.

Comment: thanks a lot - your query works as well - it's a shame I cannot pick 2 answers. Nalaka answered first and I used his answer. Thanks again.

Comment: considering he is using a subquery this answer is better. Anyway, the important is that you get that you want ;)